# Space between numbers automaticaly in an input

Tags: html, angular, web-services, frontend

I am developing a web application with Angular 8. I would like to put spaces automatically when the user entered the number of its bank account, the spaces should be in index 3, 7 and 24. To be more concrete, when the user entered the first 3 numbers, the 4th number is automatically placed after the space created. I also attach you a screenshot of the expected result.

[image: Bank account]

I have the following input :

```
<input type="text" formControlName="RibAutoriteAdministrative" required class="form-control" >
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+automatic+space+input+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: What about adding <input (change)="somethingChanged()"> and add a space to your input text